# Naming the control variable in the "for" loop

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

The functional code is available below:

```sh
:: The INDEX control variable is causing the error.
FOR /L %%INDEX IN (%1, %2, %3) DO ECHO %%INDEX

:: Syntax
FOR /L %%parameter IN (start, step, end) DO command
```

I run this script as follows:

```sh
test.bat 0 1 5
```

I get the following error:

```sh
%INDEX was unexpected at this time.
```

I noticed that this error occurs because of the character count of the control variable (`INDEX`) in the `FOR` loop. If I update the `INDEX` control variable to be a single character (such as `X`), the program works as expected.

What are the rules for naming a control variable in a `FOR` loop?

Comment: The syntex error hints at your problem. For variables cannot be named, they are single character metavariables

Comment: Not only single-character, but single case-sensitive character. A-Z. Certainly not numeric. *some* symbols work, but are generally avoided as being undocumented.

Comment: Not for the faint of heart: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56246879/12343998

Comment: I recommend to read also chapter __issue 7: Usage of letters ADFNPSTXZadfnpstxz as loop variable__ in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) and my answer on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564) Do not use `GOTO :EXIT`, use `GOTO :EOF` or `EXIT /B` (or `GOTO ENDBATCH` with a label `:ENDBATCH` if there is anything below this label like `ENDLOCAL` or `PAUSE`).

Comment: It would be also a good idea to read my answer on [Symbol equivalent to NEQ, LSS, GTR, etc. in Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47386323/3074564) with full explanation of string comparison done with command __IF__. The __IF__ condition as currently written results in an exit of batch file processing because of a syntax error on calling the batch file with `BatName.cmd "Argument 1"  "Argument 2"  "Argument 3"`. The condition should be `IF "%~3" == "" EXIT /B` to work independent on batch file called with arguments enclosed in `"` or not enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: [This link](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) has rules for naming parameters in a for loop. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: Strangely, I'd call it a `control variable` rather than a `parameter`...

Answer (score 0):

```
:: Syntax
FOR /L %%parameter IN (start, step, end) DO command
```

Here `%%parameter` must be *a **single letter** replaceable parameter*. Run `for /?` in an open `cmd` Window:

```
for /?
Runs a specified command for each file in a set of files.

FOR %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]

  %variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter.
  (set)      Specifies a set of one or more files.  Wildcards may be used.
  command    Specifies the command to carry out for each file.
  command-parameters
             Specifies parameters or switches for the specified command.

To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.

If Command Extensions are enabled, the following additional
forms of the FOR command are supported:
…
FOR /L %variable IN (start,step,end) DO command [command-parameters]

    The set is a sequence of numbers from start to end, by step amount.
    So (1,1,5) would generate the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 and (5,-1,1) would
    generate the sequence (5 4 3 2 1)
…
```