# Replace the Value in Special Parameter (%%A) in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, replace, windows-10, file-extension

I'd like to take the file extension from parameter `%%A`, and replace it with a different file extension.

```
for %%A in (C:\TEMP\TEST-AREA\*.fileext1) do (
    if "%%~xA"==".fileext1" perl -ne "print unless $a{$_}++" %%A > %%A.fileext2
)
```

For instance, the above code reads in `temp1.fileext1`, `temp2.fileext1`, `temp3.fileext1`, etc.

I want to read in the files and replace the extensions with `.fileext2`, instead of simply adding `.fileext2` to the parameter (as shown above), (i.e. `temp1.fileext1.fileext2`, `temp2.fileext1.fileext2`, `temp3.fileext1.fileext2`, etc.)

I want the parameters (or output variables) to have the file extension of `.fileext2` (i.e. `temp1.fileext2`, `temp2.fileext2`, `temp3.fileext2`, etc.)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Things like this are a _lot_ easier to do in PowerShell. Any particular reason you're not using PowerShell?

Comment: The quick fix would be to replace `%%A > %%A.fileext2` with `"%%A" > "%%~dpnA.fileext2"`. However please be aware that this method using `…*.fileext1` due to the Windows default setting of enabled 8.3 naming, could return files which begin with that extension, not those which exactly match it. You could try it with files like `.xls` and .`xlsx` for instance, and it will return both, and that may not be wanted behavior.

Comment: If you wanted to ensure that only the seeked extensions were returned, _(meaning there would be no need whatsover to include an `If` command using `%%~xA` )_, then you could use this instead, `For /F Delims^= %%A In ('Set "PathExt=" ^& where.exe "C:\TEMP":"TEST-AREA*.fileext1" 2^>NUL') Do perl -ne "print unless $a{$_}++" "%%A" >"%%~dpnA.fileext2"`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232408/change-file-extension-in-batch

Comment: Hi @Compo Thank you very much for this. All I needed was the "%%~dpnA.fileext2" and my script worked perfectly. Fyi, in this instance, there will never be an occasion where a file would begin with that extension so I'm happy to simply modify my script accordingly. Appreciate you going the extra mile as well! Cheers!

Comment: @BillyJ, if that's the case, you don't need to use an `If` command with `%%~xA`, and you should still use doublequotes, unless you can also guarantee that no `TEST-AREA*.fileext1` files can ever contain spaces or other poison characters anywhere within their paths or names. Regardless, it is still best practice to use double-quotes, in order that your code can be used as a template for other tasks without unnecessary modification. `@For %%G In ("C:\TEMP\TEST-AREA\*.fileext1") Do @"C:\perl\bin\perl.exe" -ne "print unless $a{$_}++" "%%G" >"%%~dpnG.fileext2"`